# How connect Arduino with WiFi shield to html?

Tags: javascript, html, arduino

I have to control my Arduino One with an html page.
I tried to look on the internet for possible solutions, specifically from the Arduino site, but none of them solved the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets take that you want ON/OFF a device.
Check out these examples. Using an appropriate relay switch instead of the LEDs may help you.

[Arduino-WebServer-controlled-LED](http://www.instructables.com/id/Arduino-WebServer-controlled-LED/?ALLSTEPS)

[web-server-LED-control](https://startingelectronics.org/tutorials/arduino/ethernet-shield-web-server-tutorial/web-server-LED-control/)

[web-switch-tutorial](http://www.hobbyist.co.nz/?q=web-switch-tutorial)